# Some image undisplayed in ImageView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-studio

I create an SMS app and I want to display picture of contact, I got the InputStream with:

```
public InputStream openPhoto(long contactId) {
    Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactId);
    Uri photoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri, ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(photoUri, new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.PHOTO}, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) {
        return null;
    }
    try {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            byte[] data = cursor.getBlob(0);
            if (data != null) {
                return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
            }
        }
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then I display these like this:

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(listMessage.get(position).photo);
imageContact.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

and here is what happen:

first when I run my app when I scroll down, there are some image which are displayed but when I scroll up to the top then go back to the end the image disappear [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FwMQ.jpg)

As u can see I don't have the first Image in my list, only the last 
so my fist problem is, why the first Image of my contact "Nico Aragon'" and "Elouuuuuuudie" don't display?
the second problem, why when my listView is "refreshing" the last Image disappear? :/

Here is my custom listView adapter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/tvContact"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/im_photoContact"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lastSms"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/lastSms" />

    <ImageView
        android:contentDescription="@string/photoContact"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/im_photoContact"
        android:minWidth="50dp"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:maxHeight="50dp"
        android:maxWidth="50dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/lastSms"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxWidth="300dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#c4c4c4"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/im_photoContact"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/im_photoContact"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/im_photoContact"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/new_message"
        android:id="@+id/im_new_message"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and my listview :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#f4f4f4">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/message"
            android:theme="@android:style/DeviceDefault.ButtonBar.AlertDialog" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/ListView01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is my listView Adapter :

```
public class ContactAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


    ArrayList<CreateContactAdapter> listMessage;
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater Inflater;

    public ContactAdapter(ArrayList<CreateContactAdapter> listMessage, Context context) {
        this.listMessage = listMessage;
        this.context = context;
        Inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listMessage.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listMessage.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        RecordHolder holder = null;

        if (convertView == null) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_items, parent, false);
            holder = new RecordHolder();

            holder.tvContact = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvContact);
            holder.lastSms = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lastSms);
            holder.imageContact = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.im_photoContact);
            holder.newMsg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.im_new_message);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (RecordHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        if (listMessage.get(position).photo != null) {
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(listMessage.get(position).photo);
            holder.imageContact.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        } else {
            holder.imageContact.setImageResource(R.drawable.contacticon);
        }
        if (!listMessage.get(position).contact.equals("no"))
            holder.tvContact.setText(listMessage.get(position).contact);
        else
            holder.tvContact.setText(listMessage.get(position).address);
        if (listMessage.get(position).read == 0) {
            holder.newMsg.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.new_message);
        } else
            holder.newMsg.setBackgroundResource(0);
        holder.lastSms.setText(listMessage.get(position).body);
        //On retourne l'item créé.
        return convertView;
    }

    public int getImageId(String imageName) {
        return context.getResources().getIdentifier(imageName, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
    }

    static class RecordHolder {
        TextView tvContact, lastSms;
        ImageView imageContact , newMsg;
    }
```

this is where i use openPhoto, in my mainActivity when i retrieve contact and their information:

```
cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(uriSms, selectionSms, null, null, "date DESC");
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        id = cursor.getString(2);
        if (!(idList.contains(id))) {
            body = cursor.getString(1);
            numero = cursor.getString(3);
            read = cursor.getInt(5);
            cursorPhone = this.getContentResolver().query(uriPhone, selectionPhone, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + "='" + numero + "'", null, null);
            if (cursorPhone.moveToFirst()) {
                contact = cursorPhone.getString(0);
                Uri uriContact = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(numero));
                cursorContact = this.getContentResolver().query(uriContact, selectionContact, null, null, null);
                cursorContact.moveToFirst();
                long idContact = cursorContact.getLong(0);
                photo = openPhoto(idContact);
                if (photo != null)
                    listContact.add(new CreateContactAdapter(contact, numero, body, id, photo, read));
                else
                    listContact.add(new CreateContactAdapter(contact, numero, body, id, null, read));
            } else {

                listContact.add(new CreateContactAdapter("no", numero, body, id, null, read));
            }
            idList.add(id);
        }
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
}
cursor.close();
adapter = new ContactAdapter(listContact, this);
}
```

where i set my adapter :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

final String packageName = MainActivity.this.getPackageName();
if (!Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(MainActivity.this).equals(packageName)) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Telephony.Sms.Intents.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT);
    intent.putExtra(Telephony.Sms.Intents.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, packageName);
    startActivity(intent);
}

toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);

setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false); //enlever le titre originel
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true); // ajout du bouton retour
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); // ajout du bouton retour

listContact = new ArrayList<>();
idList = new ArrayList<>();

getInfoMain();
lv.setAdapter(adapter);

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String persoId = listContact.get(position).id;
        String numero = listContact.get(position).address;
        String contact = listContact.get(position).contact;
        String body = listContact.get(position).body;
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PrintMessage.class);
        intent.putExtra("id", persoId);
        intent.putExtra("numero", numero);
        intent.putExtra("contact", contact);
        markMessageRead(ctx, numero, body);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

}

listMessage.get(position).photo = contain [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vliL5.jpg)
this is the result of openPhoto, this is an inputStream

Comment: Can you please include code of ListView Adapter here ?

Comment: i updated it sorry, this is the third code

Comment: I dont want xml code here . I want java code of ListView Adapter .

Comment: oh sorry i think it's ok now

Comment: In which context do you use `openPhoto`? Can't find in your code where it is used. Is `photo` field of `CreateContactAdapter` the result of `openPhoto` method?

Comment: i added my mainActivity where i use openPhoto, in createContactAdapter, i add the result of openPhoto just

Comment: You have very crazy code .

Comment: Where you are initializing adapter ?

Comment: haha, crazy code u think? my adapter is initialized with the method which use cursor above, I updated it

Comment: You have included lot of details in your question but that is totally confusing .

Comment: well i thought the problem was clear :/

Answer (score 0):

Replace getView() of ContactAdapter.java with following code :

```
            @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    RecordHolder holder = null;

    if (convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_items, parent, false);
        holder = new RecordHolder();

    holder.tvContact = (TextView) layoutItem.findViewById(R.id.tvContact);
    holder.lastSms = (TextView) layoutItem.findViewById(R.id.lastSms);
    holder.imageContact = (ImageView) layoutItem.findViewById(R.id.im_photoContact);
    holder.newMsg = (ImageView) layoutItem.findViewById(R.id.im_new_message);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (RecordHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }


    if (listMessage.get(position).photo != null) {
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(listMessage.get(position).photo);
        holder.imageContact.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    } else {
        holder.imageContact.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.contacticon);
    }
    if (!listMessage.get(position).contact.equals("no"))
        tvContact.setText(listMessage.get(position).contact);
    else
        holder.tvContact.setText(listMessage.get(position).address);
    if (listMessage.get(position).read == 0) {
        holder.newMsg.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.new_message);
    } else
        holder.newMsg.setBackgroundResource(0);
    holder.lastSms.setText(listMessage.get(position).body);
    //On retourne l'item créé.
    return convertView;
}
```

OutSide the getView() create a RecordHolder

```
static class RecordHolder {
    TextView tvContact, lastSms;
    ImageView imageContact , newMsg;
}
```

Comment: where di you get `mContext` ? i guess this is the context of the activity but i don't get it :/. and i can't do something like `Context ctx = this`

Comment: rename it to context , As you are getting it in the constrcutor of ContactAdapter.java .

Comment: so stupid sorry .. but always the same ://. when i debug, i got the InputStream of the image and when i come to the `if (listMessage.get(position).photo != null) {
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(listMessage.get(position).photo);
        imageContact.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    } else {
        imageContact.setImageBitmap(null);
    }` i go inside the "if" i set the image with the InputStream but didn't display it :/

Comment: What is studpid here ?

Comment: my question "where di you get mContext ? "

Comment: I have made some changes in the above answer . Plz review it . You will get mContext(Now I have renamed it context) from the corresponding Activity .(where you are calling listview.setAdapter(adapter) ).

Comment: same thing, only the last contact got their picture, first don't. i updated my code above, this is where i set my adapter, the method "getInfo" is above too, when i use Cursor.

Comment: i did some test and the conclusion is all contact's picture are good but for unknow reason they just disappear when i scroll and that the contact just go out of the screen :/ . When i go in a conversation and go back the image appear again

Comment: What you are observing , that's what you are doing in the code ,due to that images first appear and when you scroll they disappear  and appear again when a contact comes in front .

Comment: What this  listMessage.get(position).photo line returns ? Is this line returns weburl or path of SDcard ?

Comment: i updated my post with a photo to show you, but i think my problem is about my list view because i display image correctly i guess

Comment: As I have shown you are getting InputStream . Can you retrieve imageurl in listMessage.get(position).photo ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, ok I solved my problem . 
my method openPhoto (took on the official documentation android) return an InputStream, I changed it by a byte[]. then I print it:

```
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(listMessage.get(position).photo, 0, listMessage.get(position).photo.length);;
    holder.imageContact.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

but i don't know why it's working .. if someone can explain me.

thanks :)